# convert jms time stamp to current date and time

Tags: java, jms

I need to know when the message has been received thus i'm printing the jms timestamp i.e  `msg.getJMSTimestamp()` but this returns some number in milliseconds like  1300339215983. I dont undersatnd what value it is. How do i convert it to current standard date and time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
java.util.Date = new java.util.Date(msg.getJMSTimestamp());
```

Comment: worked like a charm.. but what is the value returned in msg.getJMSTimestamp(). Its in milliseconds what value does it represent.

Comment: the number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.